# multiply every member of a R list (matrices) by each other

Tags: r

I have a list of equally sized matrices in R that I want to multiply by each other.

I am looking for a way to do:

```
list$A * list$B * list$C * ...
```

Without having to type it out by hand (my list has dozens of matrices).

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Use `Reduce` if you want an element-by-element multiplication

```
> Lists <- list(matrix(1:4, 2), matrix(5:8, 2), matrix(10:13, 2))
> Reduce("*", Lists)
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]   50  252
[2,]  132  416
```

Instead of using `abind` you can use `simplify2array` function and `apply`

```
> apply(simplify2array(Lists), c(1,2), prod)
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]   50  252
[2,]  132  416
```

If you want to use `abind` then use the following:

```
> library(abind)
> apply(abind(Lists, along=3), c(1,2), prod)
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]   50  252
[2,]  132  416
```